# Renews my brain and body

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "renew" instead of "regenerate"  in my sentence?

"Sleep renews our brain and body."

Comment: You definitely do not want regenerate. Paramecium tails regenerate if you cut them off....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "renews" is a perfectly acceptable synonym to use here. I'd argue that the sentence should use the plural of brain and body, though - "Sleep renews our brains and bodies." If you leave it in the singular, it implies that we all share one brain and one body, as you'd be referring to "our brain" and "our body".

Comment: But in another sentence "These insects are unusual. They can live without a head" was wrong. But "without their head" or "heads" are both correct. Does it depend on each sentence?